# How to destroy the additional tgw route table created by terraform transit-gateway module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-modules

I have created tgw using the official transit-gateway module and I am using the default route table, Iam also seeing that the module has created an additional route table which I am not able to remove via tf code.

```html
module "transit-gateway" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/transit-gateway/aws"
  version         = "1.4.0"
  name            = var.tgw
  amazon_side_asn = 64532

  enable_auto_accept_shared_attachments = true
  vpc_attachments = {
    vpc = {
      vpc_id                                          = module.vpc.vpc_id
      subnet_ids                                      = [module.vpc.private_subnets[0]]
      dns_support                                     = true
      ipv6_support                                    = false
      transit_gateway_default_route_table_association = true
      transit_gateway_default_route_table_propagation = true
    }
  }

  ram_allow_external_principals = true
  ram_principals                = [123456789, 0987654321]

  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.env}"
    Automated   = "Terraform"
    Owner       = "${var.owner}"
    Project     = "${var.project}"
  }
}
```

Comment: How did it go with the issue? Did you find any better solution that the one I provided?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the module's source code [here](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-transit-gateway/blob/master/main.tf#L39) the only way to disable `aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table` route table creation is by setting `create_tgw` to `false`.

If you do this, you will disable entire TGW. So the answer to your question is that you can't remove them without removing entire TGW.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, if you inspect the module source code, or similar modules (as CloudPosse's) you'll see that it's creating another transit gateway route table apart from the one created by the transit gateway itself.

Make a quick test by creating a transit gateway manually in the AWS Console.

In a nutshell: If the desired result is one transit gateway route table, then you'll have to develop a module by yourself, as these modules won't use the ID of the transit gateway route table created by the transit gateway, suspecting this is because it's not possible to manage the automatically created underlying resource.